# How to match LaTeX fonts in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, fonts, latex

I created a document in LaTeX (without specifying any fonts), and now I'm trying to re-create it in LibreOffice Writer, but it looks very different due to the fonts used.

What fonts can I choose in LibreOffice that will let me match the look of LaTeX documents? I read that the default font in TeX was created by Donald Knuth and is called "Computer Modern", but it seems to be missing from the menu in LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: Side question, possibly dumb: Why doesn't LibreOffice use LaTeX fonts by default? It seems like everyone considers them more "professional".

Comment: Good question, whose answer I would also like to know.  I guess LibreOffice is following other programs like Microsoft Office?  I agree that if both followed LaTeX, maybe the world would be a better place.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Latin Modern Roman and Latin Modern Math (for mathematical expressions) fonts, which are freely available in many websites, e.g. https://www.1001fonts.com/latin-modern-roman-font.html

Download the ttf/otf files, and place them in the hidden folder `.local/share/fonts` (create it if it does not exist), and then you can choose those fonts in Libreoffice (you may have to restart your computer).

As found by OP, "Tex Gyre Deja" (installed along with LaTeX) works too.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't LaTeX using fonts that are already installed? (I'm seeing "Latin Modern Math" in the drop-down menu, but not the other one)

Comment: @bobcat Then you can directly use those. You may additionally need Latin Modern Roman, if Latin Modern Math does not work for non-math texts in Libreoffice (feel free to edit my answer).

Comment: I'm using Latin Modern Math now, and while it's closer to LaTeX than some other fonts I tried, it's obviously not the same. For example, the *italic* in LibreOffice is way more slanted than `{\it ...}`. Also `\textbf{ ...}` stays legible, while in LibreOffice the letters kind of merge together and are harder to read.

Comment: @bobcat That is why you may need Latin Modern Roman, and its variants, which is there in the link in my answer. I have used it a few times in Libreoffice, and it is closer to LaTeX than Latin Modern Math.

Comment: You're right, and LM Roman does look pretty good! Although I wonder why LM Roman needed to be installed, if I already had LaTeX.

Comment: @bobcat I don't know why the font in LaTeX does not work well in Libreoffice. I once had to quickly write a report in LibreOffice when I was still new to LaTeX (it would take much more time), and that's how I found out LM Roman.

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work. There was simply no "Computer Modern". I just tried "Tex Gyre Deja" and it's pretty good too.

Comment: @bobcat Computer Modern was the name of the original font, and the author did not want its derivatives to have the same name https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern#Derived_versions . I don't know if the actual Computer Modern is still available.

Comment: Where is .local folder on windows? I cannot find it. You told me to create it if its not there, but I don't know where "there" is supposed to be.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios You mean on Windows, the operating system, or the file manager window (press `ctrl + h` to show hidden files)?

Comment: On the file manager of windows. I have enabled to view the hidden files. Where am I supposed to create the .local folder? I see a "Local" folder in C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData. perhaps this is the folder you are talking about?

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios Sorry, I have no idea how to do it in WIndows. This site is about Ubuntu. You can ask a question at https://superuser.com/ about how to add custom fonts in Windows.